# How much of a film's sound effects do foley artists typically work on?

Tags: production, sound-effects, foley

How much of a movie's sound effects is a foley artist responsible for? Are all non-dialogue sounds rendered by them? How is this decided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Foley Artists* are responsible for a lot of different types of sounds; mostly natural sounds like footsteps and the sound that certain clothes make while moving in them, but pretty much anything that you can fit into a foley studio. In addition to *Foley Artists* there are also *Sound FX Designers* whose job is to create the sounds that can't be naturally or easily recorded.

The following text (which I grabbed from [marblehead.net](http://www.marblehead.net/foley/)) does a pretty good job of describing who's responsible for what:

> Foley does not cover sounds like car engines, explosions or other mechanical stuff - driving a car around in the studio or blowing up a building is usually not possible although we have tried! We don't do birds, laser blasts, dog barks or rain storms either!
>   [...]
>   While a Sound Editor can do very precise and repeatable effects, they have a harder time when it comes to footsteps for example, since every step is different and unique, the pace changes and the mood of the step is always different. With a good pair of shoes and years of practice, a Foley Artist can perform an actors walk perfectly on the first take while making it sound natural!

When it comes to *how much* of a film's sound effects that are actually added during post-production, an [excerpt from an article](http://www.pbs.org/newshour/art/blog/2011/02/the-sound-of-cinema.html) featuring an interview with Oscar-winning sound editor Richard King tells that it's almost all of them. Though, it most likely differs from scene to scene, and movie to movie.

> "The audience should believe that everything they hear was recorded the day the movie was shot," says King.
>
> That's far from what actually happens in a feature film. The majority of the sounds that make up a scene has to be recorded and inserted after production by a team of sound designers. The art of recreating sound effects on a stage for a film is known as foley art.